how to place the button and the input line at the same level in React
I am trying to make a page using react, now i have a input field and a button, i wanna the button's bottom edge is at the same level with the input bottom line, here is my code:
`<form className='button-container'>
            <input
              variant="outlined"
              className="bankTransSearch"
            />
            <button variant="outlined" className="bankTransSearchButton">Search</button>
            </form>`

 `.button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    }
  .bankTransSearch {
      width: 1%;
      height: 10px;
 
    }
   ` .bankTransSearchButton {
    background-color: #3f51b5 !important; 
    color: white !important;
    width: 40%;
  `
}`

now the button size is actually large and button's bottom edge is lower than the bottom edge of input, can you please help me to revise it? THANKS!
what i tried to is to search search bar style or form style, but didn't work well.

Adjust CSS styles:
At React file:
<form className='button-container'>
  <input
    variant="outlined"
    className="bankTransSearch"
    placeholder="Search"
  />
  <button className="bankTransSearchButton">Search</button>
</form>

At css file associated with previous React code:
.button-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.bankTransSearch {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.bankTransSearchButton {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px; /* adjust padding as you wish */
}

